# Business Catalyst Dynamic Menu apply 'selected' settings to Blog Children

Tags: business-catalyst

how do I get BC to apply the same CSS setting for all children of a Module?

I have a blog and I have set the menu item to the blog which works only for the Blog home page, I want all children pages to retain the same menu setting.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information would be helpful, but I think I understand your question.

The Business Catalyst menu module uses unordered lists. The class "selected" is applied to the list item relating to the page that the user is currently on.

You want to apply the same styling that is applied to the "selected" menu item to the sub-menu items?

To do this you can use CSS descendant selectors.

**CSS:**

```
.selected ul li {
    required styling
}
```

If this doesn't answer your question, please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think what Chris is asking is this:

Similarly to blog children. The Business Catalyst Photo Gallery module works is such a way that if you have more than the allotted number of photos per page, it adds pagination.

Now, when the user first selects a page with a gallery module on it, the menu should behave normally assuming the page has a place on a Business Catalyst Menu and there is appropriate `.selected` CSS applied.

The problem arises when the user clicks any of the pagination links - Next or Previous.

The url changes from this:

http://www.YourSite.com/gallery-page

To This - or some variant:

http://www.YourSite.com/Default.aspxPageID=143342&Page=2&A=PhotoGallery&PID=12350&Items=24

Because the parent list item that is referenced in the CSS is no longer the active link, the styling to the menu is no longer rendered. Typically, the menu would display as if no pages were selected.

We need a solution that includes these dynamic pagination pages and allows CSS to trickle down to them from the original Gallery page. I'd imagine this is quite similar to the blog pagination that occurs with multiple posts.